# Scoping a flow target of repository workspace in RTC Command line Interface

Tags: rtc

I have a repository workspace which has a default flow target. I want to edit the flow target and make it scoped only for few components. This is possible from RTC Eclipse Client. How can I achieve the same from RTC command line Interface. Please tell with reference to RTC 3.0.1.3.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if that API works for 3.x, or only for 4.x, but [this sequence of `lscm` commands](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Fset_flowtarget.html) seems to produced a scoped flow target:

```
# Set a component as the flow target
$ lscm workspace flowtarget TestWorkspace1 TestStream1 -C TestComp2  -r lo
Successfully updated the flow target.

# View workspace flow target that was scoped to specific components
$ lscm workspace flowtarget TestWorkspace1 TestStream1 -r <repo>
(1352) "TestStream1" (scoped) (current)
The following components flow from/to this flow target:
  (1351) "TestComp2"
```

You can see that command introduced in the [Rational Team Concert 4.0.1 M4 Milestone](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/4.0.1?p=releaseNotes), so it is possible isn't available in RTC3.x.

Comment: @KaushambiSuyal so my answer is only valid for RTC4.x then. I don't know of a way to achieve it with RTC3.

Comment: Why is the repository referenced as 'lo'?

Comment: @timmy I have edited the answer to restore links and make that repo name more generic.